# Stubbing Google Maps JS API loader in Cypress

Tags: typescript, mocking, cypress, sinon

I'm using the [Google Maps JS API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overview) in my app for autocompletion and geocoding. The API is loaded using the [Google Maps JS API Loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@googlemaps/js-api-loader). As I'm end-to-end testing with Cypress, I'm trying to mock out the API, but I can't figure out how to make it work.

I abstract the API in a separate module. This is how it is loaded and instantiated (the code is reduced to the essentials):

```js
import {Loader} from "@googlemaps/js-api-loader";

// The Google Maps API has to be loaded dynamically.
// We have to do this here as it is loaded asynchronously and otherwise we won't
//  be able to just create the class below.
let loading: Promise<typeof google>;
try {
  loading = new Loader({
    apiKey: "private key",
    libraries: ["places"],
  }).load();
} catch (e) {
  console.error("Failed to load Google Maps API");
}

class GoogleMapsAPI {
  private autocompleteService: google.maps.places.AutocompleteService;
  private readonly sessionToken: google.maps.places.AutocompleteSessionToken;
  private predictions: google.maps.places.AutocompletePrediction[];

  constructor() {
    this.autocompleteService = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();

    // As an instance is created every time we use this, we set the session here
    this.sessionToken = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteSessionToken();
    this.predictions = []
  }

  public async getPredictions(input: string): Promise<google.maps.places.AutocompletePrediction[]> {
    // Search for the input string and store the returned results
    try {
      const result = await this.autocompleteService.getPlacePredictions({
        input,
        sessionToken: this.sessionToken
      });

      // Replace the previous predictions
      this.predictions = result.results;
      return this.predictions;
    } catch (e: any) {
      console.error(`Autocomplete call failed: ${e}`);
      return [];
    }
  }
}

async function loadGoogleMapsAPI(): Promise<GoogleMapsAPI | null> {
  // Wait for the loader to load the API, then return the API class.
  try {
    await loading;

    return new GoogleMapsAPI();
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(`Google Maps API could not be loaded`);
  }

  return null;
}
```

This is how I use the API in my React app:

```js
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";

import {GoogleMapsAPI, loadGoogleMapsAPI} from "../../services/google";

export default function Site() {
  const [api, setAPI] = useState<GoogleMapsAPI | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    loadGoogleMapsAPI()
      .then((api) => {
        setAPI(api);
      })
  });

  return <div>API valid: {api ? "yes" : "no"}</div>;
}
```

And this is how I try to test it:

```js
import {Loader} from "@googlemaps/js-api-loader";


describe("Test", () => {
  it("Google Maps not found", () => {
    cy.visit(
      "/",
      {
        onBeforeLoad(win: Cypress.AUTWindow) {
          // Mock the load method of Loader to prevent it from ever requesting
          //  the Google Maps API script file
          cy.stub(Loader.prototype, "load").resolves(true);

          // Replace the Google Maps API created by the Google Maps API Loader
          //  with our mocks
          win.google = {
            maps: {
              places: {
                AutocompleteSessionToken: class {},
                AutocompleteService: class {
                  async getPlacePredictions(request: any) {
                    return Promise.resolve({ predictions: [] });
                  }
                } as any,
              } as any
            } as any
          };
        }
      }
    );

    cy.get("API valid: yes"); // Fails consistently
  });
});
```

I'm stubbing out the `load` method of the [`Loader`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overview#Loading_the_Maps_API) class and then try to add a mock Google Maps services to the window.

My problem is that neither stubbing the loader doesn't work - according to Cypress the stub is never even called and, of course, the promise doesn't resolve then either.
Another approach I tried was to stub `loadGoogleMapsAPI` and manually return an instance of `GoogleMapsAPI`, but the issue remains the same - I never get the predictions returned by `google.maps.places.autocompleteService.getPlacePredictions` via `getPlacePredictions`.

As I'm pretty new to testing with Cypress and testing frontend code in general this might just be a misundernstanding of how stubbing in Cypress works or how code is loaded in JS, but I'm pretty much stuck here and would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the issue by getting rid of the loader in favor of [inline loading](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overview#Loading_the_Maps_API) and the following code:

```js
let ready = false;

// This is the callback that is called by the Google Maps API loader script
//  loaded in index.html.
window.initGoogleMapsAPI = function() {
  ready = true;
}

async function waitForGoogleMapsAPI(): Promise<void> {
  return new Promise<void>((resolve) => {
    if (ready) {
      resolve();
    }
  })
}

...

async function loadGoogleMapsAPI(): Promise<GoogleMapsAPI | null> {
  // Wait for the loader to load the API, then return the API class.
  try {
    await waitForGoogleMapsAPI;

    return new GoogleMapsAPI();
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(`Google Maps API could not be loaded: ${e}`);
  }

  return null;
}
```

Then I export `waitForGoogleMapsAPI` and mock it in the test.